# Only display attributes that are visible on product view page on front-end if a value exists

Tags: attributes, magento-1, product-attribute, frontend, magento-community

If we have a custom attribute with the frontend properties for "Visible on Product View Page on Front-end" set to yes, then these attributes show up in our additional info box.

Even if the attribute does not have a value, it will still show up but say something like No or N/A in the additional info box.

Is there any way to make it so it will only show the value if a value exists?  For example we may have an attribute like production dimensions.  If we don't have the dimension available, I'd prefer to leave it off completely, not show N/A.

[image: example]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

one solution is to override the template file:
you can find it here : 
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml

here an exmple which i tried on Magento 1.9.0.1 rwd Package :

```
<?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): ?>
        <?php if ($_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value']) == 'Black'):?>
            <?php continue;?>
        <?php endif; ?>
            <tr>
                <th class="label"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->__($_data['label'])) ?></th>
                <td class="data"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

i just added the if statement, it checks for example if the value is Black. You can easily modify it for example with your N/A .....

Hope my answer was helpful.

Comment: What would be the best way to have multiple checks.  For example only if it says N/A or No?

Comment: Also, what about if it's empty (for example no country of manufacture)?

Comment: not working,...

Comment: Not working above mentioned code,

Answer (score 3):

Another way of doing this would be to rewrite the block `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Attributes` and change the function `getAdditionalData`

In this function you have the following section:

```
if (!$product->hasData($attribute->getAttributeCode())) {
    $value = Mage::helper('catalog')->__('N/A');
} elseif ((string)$value == '') {
    $value = Mage::helper('catalog')->__('No');
} elseif ($attribute->getFrontendInput() == 'price' && is_string($value)) {
    $value = Mage::app()->getStore()->convertPrice($value, true);
}
```

What you could do is change this part to stop the changing of $value to include 'N/A' and 'No'. Then your attributes will not be shown.

Answer (score 1):

This is correct solution which was checked on Magento **1.9.1.1**, **1.9.3.3**.

```
 <?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): ?>
    <?php if ($_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value']) == 'N/A'):?>
        <?php continue;?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if ($_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value']) == 'No'):?>
        <?php continue;?>
    <?php endif; ?>
        <tr>
            <th class="label"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->__($_data['label'])) ?></th>
            <td class="data"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>
        </tr>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a simple solution. You could try via translate. But this might give some side effects ...

translate.csv

`"Mage_Catalog::N/A",""`

Answer (score 0):

This is the ugly hack I did and it works. Notice I do checks for:

- No
- N/A
- Nein (english/german store)

  ```
      <tbody>
      <?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): ?>
          <?php if($_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) == 'Nein'){}
          elseif($_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) == 'No'){}
          elseif($_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) == 'N/A'){}else{ ?>
          <tr>
              <th class="label"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->__($_data['label'])) ?></th>
              <td class="data"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>
          </tr>
          <?php } ?>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
      </tbody>
  ```